# Detect which music from another app is playing in background

Tags: swift, background

I am trying to detect which music from another app is playing in background.

I know there is a way to detect if a music is played in background but I would like to detect which song and the time if I can. How do I do that? In Swift or Objective-c

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MediaPlayer` framework to get the current Music playing in the Music app:

```
import MediaPlayer

let player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()

let currentSongTitle = player.nowPlayingItem?.title
let currentPlaybackTime = player.currentPlaybackTime
```

Note that you need to have the `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` (aka `Privacy - Media Library Usage Description`) set to the `String` you want to present to the user when asking for permission.